# Native Mobile App - Authorized by Salesforce - Access Token

Tags: oauth2, authentication, authorization

We have SSO enabled for our org via ADFS using SAML. The single sign on is working absolutely fine.

We have an native tablet app (custom) which has an option to launch Salesforce inside the app (as iframe or webview). We had to take this approach as we do not want users to move away from app.

Now, the issue is how we authenticate / authorize Salesforce for that app and once authorized for the first time we do not want to users to authenticate / authorize again next time the app is launched next time.

App --> Initiate Login for Salesforce (redirected to ADFS) --> return back to App (store access token in key store).

I am having trouble with getting the access token and refresh token back from Salesforce after authorization. I am assuming that this is because the authentication is happening via ADFS.

I am little confused on the flow as the authorization is done by Salesforce but the authentication is via ADFS. In such case, does Salesforce still provide access and refresh token?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine SAML and Oauth together and salesforce supports this flow .You can get into the flow details in official documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sso.meta/sso/sso_mobileDT_saml_n_oauth.htm)

There is not lot of work involved to make this happen as incorporating oauth will be similar to deep linking in your flow .

You will follow below steps

1.In your salesforce environment you will create a [subdomain](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=domain_name_setup.htm) using a My domain set up .

2.Point the client at the host that your subdomain represents. This step involves defining a new host connection in the app’s settings.(This is where you will store the my domain url in the app and make sure you are relayed back to my domain for successful Authorization)

Comment: Thank you Mohith. I realized quickly that the Mobile App is connected to Salesforce via Connected App and Salesforce should be able to manage the SAML internally and generate the Access Token for the Mobile App.